# Number of primitive roots modulo p; asymptotic behavior

Tags: number-theory

I know that number of primitive roots modulo p is $\varphi(p-1)$, where $\varphi$ is Euler totient function. I'm actually interested in asymptotic behavior of $\frac{\varphi(p-1)}{p-1}$ (percentage of primitive roots among elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ ).

It's easy to see it attains it's maximum (0.5) on Fermat primes (those of form $2^n + 1$), and you can calculate a little bit to see what kind of primes correspond to some fractions, but that's not really interesting.

Do we know is there a limit of that sequence? Does it get arbitrarily close to zero? Is there a way we can speak of mean value of that sequence?

Comment: There's no limit. It does get arbitrarily close to zero, because for every $k$ there are primes of the form $kn+1$ --- so choose $k$ with lots of small prime factors.

Comment: You can have a look at Koblitz's book on Cryptography, proposition II.1.4 : 
If $(p_j)$ is a sequence of prime numbers such that $p_j \equiv 1 \pmod{ j! }$ for every $j>0$, then the probability that a random $g \in \Bbb F_{p_j}^{\times}$ is a generator tends to $0$ as $j \to \infty$, i.e. $\phi(p_j - 1)/ (p_j - 1) \to 0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A theorem is stated [here](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/primitiverootstoo.pdf): Let $D(u)$ be the relative asymptotic density in the set of all primes of the set $$\{{\,p{\rm\ prime}:\phi(p-1)/(p-1)\le u\,\}}$$ Then $D(u)$ exists for every real number $u$, $D(u)$ is a continuous function of $u$, and $D(u)$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1/2]$, with $D(0)=0$, $D(1/2)=1$. The theorem is attributed to I. Katai, On distribution of arithmetical functions on the set prime plus one, Compositio Math. 19 (1968), 278-289.